# Are there benefits to Projection Expressions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

Reading the [Projection Expressions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ProjectionExpressions.html) documentation doesn't give me enough technical details to get an idea of what exactly are we saving by using them.

1. What memory am I saving, if any. Is it on the DynamoDB side? Or is it just on the application level. If so, how does it affect performance and pricing?
2. How costlier is it to isolate nested attribute of a ddb entry compared to looking up the entry through a key.

For a little bit of context, I'm trying to decide a data structure for a multilingual project:

**Option A:**

```
{
  id: 'yes',
  en: 'Yes',
  es: 'Si'
},
{
  id: 'no',
  en: 'No',
  es: 'No'
}
```

**Option B:**

```
{
  id: 'en',
  yes: 'Yes',
  no: 'No'
},
{
  id: 'es',
  yes: 'Si',
  no: 'No'
}
```

While it might seem obvious to go for option A, I have a conflicting use case: when the client app launches it needs to get the whole batch of strings for the UI. So with option A, it might mean making batch queries for maybe 300 items. Unideal.

Comment: Hmmm... It doesn't seem to be about pricing or capacity unit consumption [*"For any operation that returns items, you can request a subset of attributes to retrieve; however, doing so has no impact on the item size calculations."*](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/CapacityUnitCalculations.html#ItemSizeCalculations.Reads) ...although it would impact the amount of data transfer bandwidth you use, which is billable separately in some conditions... but you're right, the docs seem a little sparse.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Bad News:
There seems to be no effect on pricing as it uses the same amount of RCU and you'll still hit the 1MB limit on scans.

Good News:
I"ve seen benefits on network usage, latency and throughput when dropping out large columns that arent necessarily needed for processing.  For example you create a scan that *eventually* returns 10000 items.  If you only need 10kb of the 40kb record, you're saving 300mb.